# Java How do I compare if current time is within two time ranges

Tags: java, date, time, jodatime

I have two times `String t1 = "17:00:00-07:00"` and `String t2 = "23:59:00-07:00"`, which is 5pm local time and 11:59pm local time (my time zone is PT).

Assuming I am in EST time zone. How do I know if the current time falls within t1 and t2 with the timezone difference?

I tried using:

```
ISODateTimeFormat.timeNoMillis()
        .parseDateTime(t1)
        .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
        .toLocalTime()
        .toDateTimeToday();
```

but it gives me *`17:00:00-04:00`* when I was expecting something like *`20:00:00-04:00`*.

Comment: `withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).toLocalTime()` why?

Comment: So I could convert the Date time to current date with the time

Comment: @user3709877 My answer wasn't correct the first few times but now I'm positive it's correct.

Comment: This question is not duplicate because the `String` and getting the time zone issue correct is not easy or straightforward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `ISODateTimeFormat.timeNoMillis()` will always be the appropriate parser, you want to use the [`Interval`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class for this. Also, use [`parseLocalTime()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseLocalTime(java.lang.String)) instead of `parseDateTime()` and then [convert it to a `DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#toDateTimeToday()) to **and** use the [`.withOffsetParsed()` method](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withOffsetParsed()) to ensure that the time zones get handled properly.

```
public static boolean isNowBetweenRange(String t1, String t2) {    
  DateTime time1 = normalizeString(t1);
  DateTime time2 = normalizeString(t2);

  Interval interval = new Interval(time1, time2);

  return interval.contains(DateTime.now());
}

private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMAT =
                  ISODateTimeFormat.timeNoMillis().withOffsetParsed();

private static DateTime normalizeString(String t1) {
  DateTimeZone zone = FORMAT.parseDateTime(t1).getZone();
  return FORMAT
      .parseLocalTime(t1)
      .toDateTimeToday(zone);
}
```